# How to reload jquery on onclick event?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've got a table row where it retrieves data from MySQL and I have included a .onclick function where it opens up a text editor with data inside, but the text editor is only opening for the first row and not the rest in the table.

This is the jQuery code: The first opens the text editor and the second switches the textarea for the text editor which is ckeditor.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $(".trClass").click(function()
        {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#d_'+id).css("display", "block");
            $('#table_id').css("display", "none");
        });
    }); 

    window.onload = function()
    {
        CKEDITOR.replace("editor1");
    };

</script>
```

and this here is echo for the table, I am using a foreach.

```
echo '
    <tr class="trClass" id="'.$counter.'">
        <td class="marker">
            <i class="fa fa-align-left"></i>
        </td>

        <td class="title">
            '.$article_title.'
        </td>

        <td class="content">
            '.$article_content.'
            </td>
    </tr>

    <section id="d_'.$counter.'" style="display:none;">
        <textarea id="editor1">
            <div style="width:468px;">
                '.$article_content_full.'
            </div>
        </textarea>
    </section>
';
$counter++;
}
```

I cannot figure out how to make the `CKEDITOR.replace("editor1");` load for every table, I tried using .click function within it but it does not work as it doesn't load. Here is the problem, if you click on the first row it opens the text editor if you click on the second it does not; http://www.goo.gl/dQrLPN

Comment: Well to start, that is invalid HTML. Tables do not have section elements as children.

Comment: You cannot have multiple elements with the same `id`, your code currently outputs a `<textarea id="editor1">` for each row.

Comment: @epascarello, I posted the exact answer to what you said below to WideAsleepDad's answer.

Comment: Guess what, you need to find a better way to output the data. Have you ever heard about building strings and outputting the data once? And @DaveRandom hit the head on the nail with the comment above.

Comment: @epascarello, I have not; could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically the `id` attribute should be unique for each element. Applying properties across multiple elements is usually accomplished with a `class`. Knowing this, CKEditor is probably just grabbing the first instance of an object with the given `id` (probably using `document.GetElementById` behind the scenes).

*(According to the [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR-method-replace), `CKEDITOR.replace(var)` will either take a DOM element, ID, or name.)*

Given that, you have a couple of options. One is to defer loading the CKEditor until you actually click on the table row. This would look something like this... (note how each `textarea` has a unique id)

```
<section id="d_' . $counter . '" style="display:none;">
    <textarea id="editor_'.$counter.'">
        <div style="width:468px;">
            '.$article_content_full.'
        </div>
    </textarea>
```

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".trClass").click(function()
    {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#d_'+id).css("display", "block");
        $('#table_id').css("display", "none");
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor_'+id);
    });
});
```

The second option would be to loop through all of the `textarea` elements and call replace on each one of them on-load. I wouldn't really recommend this, unless there's some specific reason you want to load everything up-front.

EDIT: Although this should fix your issue, you should look in to the HTML issues the other answerers have put forward. `<section>` doesn't belong as a child of `<table>` :-)

Comment: Your answer actually would be correct which is exactly as what I tried, but in this case for some reason it did not work. Ckeditor isn't even loading anymore, I left it live in the link I posted above.

Comment: Apologies, change the replace line to `CKEDITOR.replace('editor_'+id);`. You don't need the # here, it's not JQuery. My mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting the table and filtering by the rows using the `.on()` method.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#table_id').on('click','.trClass',function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#d_'+id).css('display', 'block');
        $('#table_id').css('display', 'none');
    });
});
```

Details on `.on()` are here: https://api.jquery.com/on/

And as noted in the comments above, there are some overall issues with your HTML that you should probably fix before proceeding further.

Comment: The problem isn't the click event firing, it's the CKEditor only loading on the first instance. In the example, the event works as expected, minus seeing the editor appear.

Comment: In that case start with correcting the HTML and try again. There are several tutorials on basic HTML.

Comment: I cannot place the section elsewhere, as I need to use the php variables inside the foreach, with that being said, I hid the <section> and once the row is clicked the table hides itself and the section appears, there isn't another way for me to accomplish it without the way I did above. I cannot place the whole table inside the foreach otherwise it'll create table after table when only the tr are necessary.